# Changing edit summary of a previous revision

Tags: bug, edits, revision-history

If I go to the revision history of an answer to edit the field "Edit Summary" of a revision, the change will not be saved unless I also edit the actual answer.

I have not tested whether this is also the case with revisions of a question.

Comment: How do you get access to edit the "Edit Summary" of a revision? I can only get an edit for the revision (that will create a new revision with its own edit summary).

Comment: No repro in the Sandbox for me...

Comment: @Oded The point here is that subsequent edits within the grace period *that only change the edit summary* are ignored.

Comment: @Servy that seems illogical. If you make an edit and enter the edit summary incorrectly, you should be able to go into the revision and change the edit summary.

Comment: @TomRedfern I didn't say it was a good idea, just that that's how it works.  I assumed it was a bug nobody bothered to fix.

Comment: @Servy Noted. Didn't mean to suggest you were arguing that it should work as such